Custom logs configuration
I have server for mailing using postfix
i want to make configuration which generate logs like this name ECMPLOG how to configure it please help
Jul  2 02:50:01 crmail7 postfix/smtp[5914]: ECMPLOG : BC5F2C5CAB3|872|<root@crmail7.infimail.com>|<root@crmail7.infimail.com>|DOM|202.162.242.150[202.162.242.150]:25|162.243.208.38->250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D77EA18BB8C6F|0|1719868801|sent
I also tried to make changes in rsyslog conf but didnt work in my case
